# How to get all tickets of a group trough official Zendesk API PHP client?

Tags: php, api, zendesk

I'm using the offical [Zendesk PHP API client](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php) but I cannot find any documentation on how to get all tickets of a special group.

I already studied the README.MD on GitHub, the samples and also source code of the framework but I could not figure it out.

I have the group ID, but it would also be possible to search the tickets with a tag. Unfortunately I am not able to search for tickets, just for users.

Comment: Or is the last opportunity to loop through the users and count all tickets of the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days Zendesk support got back to me, and the solution is quite simple if you know how:

With `$client->search()->find('type:ticket group:GROUP_NAME')` you can use all query parameters described in the Zendesk API Documentation.